# Google map custom marker with css rounded corner

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have managed to use and apply my own marker on google map as below.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: point,
                            map: map,                          
                            icon: pIcon,
                            optimized:false
                        });
```

I would like to add a round corner background to it like below css

```
#orangeIcon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  overflow: hidden;
    border-top-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FFBF00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #FFBF00;

    background-color: #FFBF00;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #FFBF00;


}
```

how achieve this for google map ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of version 3.17, the google.maps.Marker objects exists in the [`markerLayer` pane](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapPanes)  which is just a fancy name for a div.

To get a reference to the markerLayer you need to create an OverlayView Object. Now, this object is a bit abstract. You need to implement a draw function for it to work. For example, open the [basic example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple) in a new tab and paste this to the console

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw=function() {};

overlay.setMap(map);

overlay.getPanes();
```

it returns:

```
{
    floatPane: div
    floatShadow: div
    mapPane: div
    markerLayer: div
    overlayImage: div
    overlayLayer: div
    overlayMouseTarget: div
    overlayShadow: div
}
```

Thay markerLayer is a div which contains the markers. If I create your marker using a given  icon image,

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map,                          
                icon: 'http://ruralshores.com/assets/marker-icon.png',
                optimized:false
             });
```

My markerLayer will be:

[image]

Where the selected div (the one with z-index 103) is the markerLayer.

If you wanted to access the markerLayer programatically, you could add a "markerLayer" class to it after getting its reference with the `getPanes` method. I guess that every image inside the markerLayer is a marker, so you could style it at will.

**TL/DR** : you can style it, provided you went through all the trouble of finding the DOM reference to your marker.

Edit: [I made a bl.ocks for you to check](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254)

Comment: I am a bit lost what I want is that to have my .css and in it embedded with the current icon like this <div id='orangeIcon' style='margin: auto;'><img class='imgTest' src=\"eLogo/$eLogo\">
</div>

Comment: I know, but it isn't easy. If you want to style an element inside google maps you must first get a reference to it in the document. This is just a workaround, not at all among the limited ways that google provides to style map elements.

Comment: So how to get the exact reference cause the div dont have any id right? I am trying to figure out with my sample. Any wayto know it exactly ?

Comment: What is the best suggestion to solve is it by creating OverlayView and adding the icon then add to map? Will this be an issue later for clustering?

Comment: The overlayview is only a helper to grab the correct div. Markers are still appended to the global map instance as always. I made a bl.ocks for you to check http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254

Comment: OK I will go through it sorry a bit new to it.

Comment: heh, don't worry. Before you asked it I never really tried to style markers with CSS

Comment: I appreciate your help but I want to clarify more on these Whaat is the !important means ? #markerLayer img {
        border: 2px solid green !important;
        width: 85% !important;
        height: 90% !important;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

Comment: !important overrides a style previously defined. I don't remember why I used it, but my style was just an example.

Answer (score 14):

When you know the url of the image used for the marker you know how to access it via CSS: use a attribute-selector.

Let's create a circle-marker based on your avatar [image] with a 1px black border:

Marker-setup:

```
icon:{
       url: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a9745ea7ac5c90d7acadb02ab1020cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
       //the size of the image is 32x32, 
       //when you want to add a border you must add 2*borderWidth to the size
       size:new google.maps.Size(34,34)},
       //define the shape
       shape:{coords:[17,17,18],type:'circle'},
       //set optimized to false otherwise the marker  will be rendered via canvas 
       //and is not accessible via CSS
       optimized:false
     }
```

the CSS:

```
  img[src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a9745ea7ac5c90d7acadb02ab1020cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"]{
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000 !important;
  }
```

....done.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5raf237u/

When you use a shadow use a larger size(depending on the size of the shadow ):

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L2o2xwj3/

Comment: great tip! after all, it's the same than matching by any other attribute :)

Comment: Where do I put the img the css class and would want it to be solid? I dont see where is the color of the radius being set?

Comment: I would have multiple icon and how to set them all why say different background colors? I am not so clear on the image settings

Answer (score 4):

Hello i try all this answers but no one work as i wanna
Try this first Create a div contains the image (MarkerImage) and add CSS

```
   var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6, -74)
        };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),    mapOptions);

     // I create 3 markers using http://ruralshores.com/assets/marker-icon.png as icon
     var myIcon='http://ruralshores.com/assets/marker-icon.png';
     var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat:40.8, lng:-74}, map: map, icon: myIcon, optimized:false });
     var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat:40.6, lng:-74.5}, map: map, icon: myIcon , optimized:false });
     var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat:40.5, lng:-74.3}, map: map, icon: myIcon , optimized:false });

     // I create an OverlayView, and set it to add the "markerLayer" class to the markerLayer DIV
     var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
     myoverlay.draw = function () {
         this.getPanes().markerLayer.id='markerLayer';
     };
     myoverlay.setMap(map);

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and now add somme CSS

```
#markerLayer img {
        border: 2px solid red !important;
        width: 85% !important;
        height: 90% !important;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
```

The full Tutorial is [her](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above ,I used OverlayView

```
var AvatarMarker = function(latlng,avatarUrl,map,id){
      this.latlng = latlng;
      this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
      this.setMap(map);
      this.id= id;
    };
  AvatarMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  AvatarMarker.prototype.onAdd= function(){
    var img = document.createElement("img"),me=this;
    img.style.width="30px";
    img.style.height="30px";
    img.style.position="absolute";
    img.style.webkitBorderRadius="50%";
    img.style.borderRadius="50%";
    img.style.zIndex="999";
    img.src=me.avatarUrl;
    this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(img);
    me.img= img;
    img.onclick = function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger(me,"click",{id:me.id});
    }
  };
  AvatarMarker.prototype.draw = function(){
    this.setLatLng(this.latlng);
  }
  AvatarMarker.prototype.onRemove = function(){
    this.img.parentNode.removeChild(this.img);
    this.img =  null;
  }
  AvatarMarker.prototype.setLatLng = function(latlng){
    if(!this.getProjection()) return ;
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection(),
      xy=overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(latlng);
    this.img && (this.img.style.left=(xy.x-15)+'px');
    this.img && (this.img.style.top=(xy.y-15)+'px');
    google.maps.event.trigger(this,"draw");
  }
  AvatarMarker.prototype.getLatLng = function(){return this.latlng;}
```

and the related document is here: [customoverlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays)

Answer (score -3):

Try this 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Kv99/169/) written in SCSS ([Sass](http://sass-lang.com/))

```
$radius: 10px;
$thickness: 5px;
$border-color: rgba(black, 0.15);
$background-color: white;

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;

  & > i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    &.top {
      top: 0;
      border-top: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        top: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-top: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.right {
      right: 0;
      border-right: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        right: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-right: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.bottom {
      bottom: 0;
      border-bottom: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        bottom: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-bottom: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.left {
      left: 0;
      border-left: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        left: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-left: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }

    &.top:not(.right):not(.left),
    &.bottom:not(.right):not(.left) {
      height: $thickness;
      left: $radius+$thickness;
      right: $radius+$thickness;
    }

    &.left:not(.top):not(.bottom),
    &.right:not(.top):not(.bottom) {
      width: $thickness;
      top: $radius+$thickness;
      bottom: $radius+$thickness;
    }

    &.top.right,
    &.top.left,
    &.bottom.right,
    &.bottom.left {
      width: $radius;
      height: $radius;

      &:after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        width: 1.5*$radius;
        height: 1.5*$radius;
      }
    }

    &.top.right {
      border-top-right-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-top-right-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.top.left {
      border-top-left-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-top-left-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.bottom.right {
      border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.bottom.left {
      border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
  }
}

#map {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  .gmnoprint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: No I am not looking for the map I am looking for the marker to have rounded corner. I have the .css ready but not sure how to integrate it